# Cocos2d v3.0 - Using Physics Editor with animations

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to use Physics Editor to create custom physics for my sprites, which are animated.  I am following the guide from https://www.codeandweb.com/blog/2014/04/09/using-physicseditor-with-cocos2d-v3, but it doesn't show what to do with animations.

Below is the code where I have my animations:

```
//adding the png with all the sprites(run)
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"run-hd.plist"];
CCSpriteBatchNode *runSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"run-hd.png"];
[self addChild:runSheet];

//The sprite animation(run)
NSMutableArray *runAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
{
    [runAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Run%d-HDN.png", i]]];
}
CCAnimation *runAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:runAnimFrames delay:0.1f]; //Speed in which the frames will go at

//Adding png to sprite
_character = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Run1-HDN.png"];
_character.position  = ccp(100,80);

//Repeating the sprite animation
CCActionAnimate *runAnimationAction = [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:runAnim];
CCActionRepeatForever *runRepeatingAnimation = [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:runAnimationAction];

//Animation continuously repeating
[_character runAction:runRepeatingAnimation];

//Adding the Sprite to the Scene
_character.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, _character.contentSize} cornerRadius:0];
_character.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"playerGroup";
_character.physicsBody.collisionType  = @"playerCollision";
_character.scale = 2;
[_physicsWorld addChild:_character];
```

I created the .plist with the custom physics body in Physics Editor, is there a way to add it to my code?  Or is there another way to get this done?
Thanks!

Comment: I totally recommend you to use SpriteBuilder with cocos2dV3. It is very simple, and you will have it attached to your code with just a click. Even the animations. Now with the new version you can even make complex physic shapes. That's my recommendation. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Just in case anyone needed to know, here is what I did.  First I needed to add the GCCShapeCache classes found here https://github.com/CodeAndWeb/PhysicsEditor-Cocos2D-V3/tree/master/PhysicsEditor-Cocos2D-V3/Classes to my project.  Then I added

```
#import "GCCShapeCache.h"
```

to my HelloWorldScene.m class and added the .plist file created in Physics Editor into my project.  I then added

```
[[GCCShapeCache sharedShapeCache] addShapesWithFile:@"run.plist"];
[[GCCShapeCache sharedShapeCache] setBodyWithName:@"Run1-HDN" onNode:_character];
```

and my custom shape was added to my project.